# android enabling/disabling notifications

Tags: android, mobile, notifications, push-notification

I am new to android developing and building an app. I am trying pop a notification whenever an announcement is recorded into my database. However, not everyone likes notifications therefore there should be an option which disables/enables notifications only for my app. I am wondering if this can be done for the android versions 2.1 and upper.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course. Just use a boolean variable to check if user has set notifications enabled or disabled and store it in your [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

Each time you need to launch a notification, check the variable; Launch the notification if it's true and don't launch it if it's false.

Comment: Yes the same technique i am using in my app

Comment: Anup thank you so much for your quick reply. I still have a question in my mind. this boolean variable will be kept even I close the device, right?

Comment: Yes. All variables stored in SharedPreferences are persistent.

Comment: Thank you again so much Anup, that gives me a good starting point.